# Firebase Storage image upload

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am using the following method to save information.

```
    private void saveUserData() {
    progressDialog.setTitle("Account Settings");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait while settings are being changed...");
    progressDialog.show();

    final StorageReference imageRef = storageReference
            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
    imageRef.putFile(imageUri);
}
```

I have removed some lines of code for accessing the database.

This the log cat description.

*E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
     Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: FirebaseStorage-Upload-1*

I seached this error code and found

*case unknown = -13000*

The app doesn't crash when I comment this line.

```
imageRef.putFile(imageUri);
```

On a side note, I am able to save text info successfully and even retrieve it from the database.

*EDIT*

Here is the code.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
            .getReference().child("Profile Pictures");

    profileImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, galleryPick);
        }
    });
    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            saveUserData();
        }
    });
    retrieveUserInformation();
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == galleryPick && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        imageUri = data.getData();
        profileImageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more code. I try to check the bug from this code but not enough data. maybe it's was bug on another line such as 
**storageReference** is not initial correctly
`FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()` ??? about **.getInstance()** ???

Comment: Given the variable name `imageUri`, you're trying to upload to Storage from a URL, which is not supported. You'll first have to download the data from the URL, and then upload it to Storage.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I appreciate your support. But, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48433212/firebase-storage-image-upload-android the person is able to do upload using Uri.

Answer (score 1):

Given the variable name `imageUri`, you're trying to upload to Storage from a URL, which is not supported. You'll first have to download the data from the URL, and then upload it to Storage.